# Is there a pgRouting-like library for MySQL?

Tags: routing, mysql

As described in the [OsmDB.pm](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OsmDB.pm) page I have created a schema in MySQL from an OSM file. Now I have to find the length of the shortest path between two given points (preferably using the A* algorithm). How do I do this? I know pgRouting is the library for PostGIS/PostgreSQL. Is there a similar library for MySQL or can I achieve this using an SQL query?